# Ajax call fails in Intel XDK hybrid mobile App - live deployment

Tags: android, ajax, intel-xdk

I am fighting a big problem here for 2 days. I have created a hybrid mobile  app in Intel XDK. The app makes remote Ajax calls to my server. Everything went fine. Tested in Emulator and everything went fine. Also tested in App preview by connecting my Android device to my MAC - this also went fine.

Now, it was time to build and generate the APK file. After I installed the APK in my Android device, all the Ajax calls have failed. It simply shows blank.

I then checked some forums and have also made "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *" in my server. Even this did not help. My Ajax calls are not responding or is being blocked - I don’t know.

I am using the latest version of Intel XDK. I have also included both the intelxdk.js and xhr.js within the HEAD tag.

USB Debugging is fine and works. But, I have no idea how to debug this live deployment. What else can I try.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There is a known ajax issue with apk built with latest Intel XDK on Android > 4.4, this is due to the version of `Cordova CLI 4.1.2`.

In the Intel XDK -> project settings -> build settings for Android, change the Cordova CLI version from `4.1.2` to `3.5` and ajax should work again. We are working on a fix when using latest CLI

Also u dont need intelxdk.js and xhr.js if you are building Cordova builds.

Comment: Thank you very much. This has fixed the problem. Actually, I use App framework. Further, I am also using XMLHttpRequest, so I think, both intelxdk.js and xkr.js are required. One other question. When I make the version of Cordova to 3.5, Intel XDK asks to upgrade the Plugins. Perhaps the plugins version do not match with the Cordova version. So, if this is an Intel XDK bug, then we should not use the latest version - Right.

Comment: u dont need intelxdk.js and xhr.js if you are building with Cordova, u only need it if u use legacy builds. cordova.js is replacement for intelxdk.js and xhr.js when using Cordova build options in intelXDK. Currently we know ajax is not working with cli 4.1.2 for some android versions, so 3.5 is workaround, we are investigating...